# how to remove and add uiTapGestureRecognizers on pop-upviewsthat are in uiview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

if dere r 3 pop-ups n out of which i want gesture recognizrs only on 2 pop-ups bt not on left one ....Is it possible???or i have to make seperate pop up for it?

in my project i have a uiview over which i have implemented various buttons on click of them dey will open different pop-ups and i want to hide pop-ups when i click on them but on one btn click i want not to hide that pop-up view ....so i write this code

```
[popup_view removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Comment: plz gimme any suggestion....whether to take new pop-up view or is there is a way to hide gesture...????

Comment: plz answer my question..

Comment: please clarify a bit more the view layout, and also it is not clear why you want to use gesture recognisers to create 3 UIButtons with actions to create popup alertviews/uiviews?